# Changing colour based on RGB values in a grouped bar plot with plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I wrote this code to generate a grouped bar chart:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
class_list = ['class1','class2','class3','class4','class5']
average_length = [10,20,50,30,50]
num_entries = [83,38,83,57,34]
col_Type = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"]

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Average Cars Per Area', x=class_list, y=average_length), #color=col_Type,
    go.Bar(name='Cars Per Length', x=class_list, y=num_entries), #color = col_Type
])
# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')

#colours = {
#    'class_list': "#0C3B5D",
#    'num_entries': "#3EC1CD",
#    'average_length': "#EF3A4C" 
#}


fig.update_layout(title_text='Average Cars Per Area and Length',
                  title_x=0.1,
                  plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                  paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                  bargap=0.30,
                  bargroupgap=0.0,
                  margin=dict(l=50, r=50, t=50, b=50),
                  xaxis_title="Score Class",
                  yaxis_title="Gene Length/Number of Proteins",
                  yaxis = dict(
                  tickfont = dict(size=13)),
#         color_discrete_map = colours,    
                  xaxis = dict(
                  tickfont = dict(size=13)),)



#fig.update_traces(marker_color=['red', 'green'], showlegend=False)
#fig.update_traces(marker_color=['rgba(135, 206, 250, 0.5)',
#               'rgba(400, 206, 250, 0.5)',
#               'rgba(135, 206, 250, 0.5)',
#               'rgba(400, 206, 250, 0.5)',
#               'rgba(135, 206, 250, 0.5)',
#               'rgba(400, 206, 250, 0.5)',
#               'rgba(135, 206, 250, 0.5)',
#               'rgba(400, 206, 250, 0.5)',
#               'rgba(135, 206, 250, 0.5)',
#               'rgba(400, 206, 250, 0.5)'], showlegend=False)

fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black')
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black')
```

fig.show()

The output is:

[image]

I want to change the colours of the bars based on specifying RGB values. I can see answers about how to do this on various places (e.g. [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-set-the-color-of-individual-bars-of-a-waterfall-chart/31477), [here](https://pretagteam.com/question/plotly-how-to-specify-colors-for-a-group-using-gobar), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68403305/change-color-of-each-bar-in-a-grouped-bar-chart-plotly-to-custom-colors)). But as you can see from my attempts that I've commented out, I'm struggling to get their solutions to to work for me.

Could someone demonstrate how to change the bar colours based on RGB values?

Edit 1:
leaving a solution here in case it helps anyone. Here's a way to do it with matplotlib.

```
# libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline  
# set width of bars
barWidth = 0.25
 
# set heights of bars
bars1 = [10,20,50,30,50]
bars2 = [83,38,83,57,34]
 
# Set position of bar on X axis
r1 = np.arange(len(bars1))
r2 = [x + barWidth for x in r1]

 
# Make the plot
plt.bar(r1, bars1, color='#7f6d5f', width=barWidth, edgecolor='white', label='var1')
plt.bar(r2, bars2, color='#557f2d', width=barWidth, edgecolor='white', label='var2')
 
# Add xticks on the middle of the group bars
plt.xlabel('group', fontweight='bold')
plt.xticks([r + barWidth for r in range(len(bars1))], ['class1','class2','class3','class4','class5'])
 
# Create legend & Show graphic
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I haven't added it as an answer, because the original title was 'with plotly', which this doesn't solve.

Comment: " I can see answers about how to do this on various places (e.g. here, here, here). But as you can see from my attempts that I've commented out, I'm struggling to get their solutions to to work for me." I can't see how your attempts have anything to do with the advice there. In particular, in none of the other code samples can I see anything to do with `.update_traces`, and the only place I can see `marker_color` used as a parameter, is directly when creating a `go.Bar`.

Comment: So I'm not really sure how to help you here. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, and if you don't understand those examples, why would you understand ours?

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel, .update_traces is when you scroll down on the code, you can see I was trying to add an RGB to each bar individually but it added it to each pair of bars. But for sure point taken that I might not understand attempts here, thanks a mil will switch library and try something else. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again @KarlKnechtel, I solved it with matplotlib and added it as a comment in the question. I didn't add it as a solution here as the original title says 'with plotly' which my solution does not solve. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of the bar graph can be set to any color in the marker color.

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Average Cars Per Area', x=class_list, y=average_length, marker_color='red'),
    go.Bar(name='Cars Per Length', x=class_list, y=num_entries, marker_color='green')
])
```

[image]